# Summing values in nested dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a nested Python dictionary:

```
dct={1: {'13C': (13, 'C'), '6C': (6, 'C'), '13D': (13, 'D'), '10D': (10, 'D'), '7H': (7, 'H'), '5H': (5, 'H'), '5D': (5, 'D')}, 2: {'6C': (6, 'C'), '10D': (10, 'D'), '7H': (7, 'H'), '14D': (14, 'D'), '5H': (5, 'H'), '5D': (5, 'D'), '14C': (14, 'C')}}
```

I'm looking to extract the numbers only for each of the sub-dictionaries, determine the highest 5 numbers and then sum them. My code so far (and I've tried many variations as well as other suggestion for other similar posts in itertools):

```
    for player in dct:
        print player
        print dct[player]
        for cards in dct[player].keys():
            print cards
```

The desired outcome:

The entry '5D' and '5H' are the lowest (in this case) for the first and the second entries, therefore they would not be included in the sum. Therefore the outcome for the first entry `first=13+6+13+10+7` and `second=6+10+7+14+14`. So `first=49` and `second=51`. How to do this calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to iterate through all subdictionaries, and then extract the values. Find the five highest values, and sum those:

```
>>> for key, subdictionary in dct.items():
        values = [x[0] for x in subdictionary.values()]
        values.sort(reverse=True)
        print(key, sum(values[:5]))

1 49
2 51
```

Comment: what are you using `key` for?

Comment: @timgeb Only in the output, to print the key of the subdictionary within the outer dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

if you want the n largest you can use [nlargest](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest):

```
from operator import itemgetter
from heapq import nlargest
n = 5

maxes = [(k, sum(nlargest(n, map(itemgetter(0), v.values())))) 
          for k, v  in dct.items()]
```

output:

```
[(1, 49), (2, 51)]
```

Or if you just want the sums:

```
maxes = [(sum(nlargest(n, map(itemgetter(0), v.values())))) 
          for v  in dct.values()]
```

Which would give you:

```
[49, 51]
```

Answer (score 0):

`result = [sum(sorted([ int(x[:-1]) for x in dct[key]])[-5:]) for key in dct]`

if you also need the keys:

`result = [(key, sum(sorted([int(x[:-1]) for x in dct[key]])[-5:])) for key in dct]`

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the numbers like so

```
numbers = [sum(sorted([y[0] for x, y in v.iteritems()])[-5:]) for k, v in dct.iteritems()]
print numbers  # [49, 51]
```

Comment: I don't think this guarantees `numbers` having the right order, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
>>> {k:sum(sorted((x[0] for x in v.values()))[-5:]) for k,v in dct.items()}
{1: 49, 2: 51}
```